# Improving python classes' methods

Tags: python, oop, python-class

I have come across an issue during set-up python classes. I have such classes:

```
class ModifierType(ABC):
    """Represents a generic modifier type."""
    ...


class DefaultModifierType(ModifierType):
    """Represents a default modifier type."""

    @staticmethod
    def check_modifier(modifier_id: str, item_name: str, default_modifiers: tuple[str]) -> None:
        ...


@dataclass
class RequiredModifierType(ModifierType):
    """Represents a required modifier type."""

    default_quantity: int = None
    action_codes: list[str] = field(default_factory=list)

    def check_modifier(self, modifier_id: str, item_name: str) -> None:
        ...


@dataclass
class Modifier:
    """Represents a generic modifier of group."""

    modifier_id: str
    modifier_type: ModifierType
```

And now I also have the outer function that runs kind of such code:

```
if isinstance(modifier.modifier_type, RequiredModifierType):
    modifier.modifier_type.check_modifier(
        modifier_id=modifier.modifier_id,
        item_name=item_name
    )
elif isinstance(modifier.modifier_type, DefaultModifierType):
    modifier.modifier_type.check_modifier(
        modifier_id=modifier.modifier_id,
        item_name=item_name,
        default_modifiers=default_modifiers
    )
```

**The issue:** as I figured out I cannot create an abstract method for `ModifierType` class because it has different params in `DefaultModifierType` and `RequiredModifierType` respectively. So I'd like to know if there's any opportunity to create this abstract method? If not, the checks better to move into `Modifier` class and check the instance of `modifier_type` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some further arguments, give them a default value, and ignore them where they are irrelevant or don't make sense.

```py
class ModifierType():

    @staticmethod
    def check_modifier(modifier_id: str, item_name: str, default_modifiers: tuple[str] = None) -> None:
        ...

class DefaultModifierType(ModifierType):
    """Represents a default modifier type."""

    @staticmethod
    def check_modifier(modifier_id: str, item_name: str, default_modifiers: tuple[str]) -> None:
        assert (default_modifiers is not None)
        ...
```

However, if they really do have quite different signatures, it is worth considering that the two methods are not conceptually the same, and *should* be different methods that the calling side needs to explicitly distinguish.

Comment: so I don't need to use ```ABC``` and ```@abstractmethod``` in principle?

Comment: Ah, I'm afraid I am not experienced with using `ABC`. But I am not sure it is relevant to the question. Unless a method decorated with `@abstractmethod` is not allowed to have default parameters? I think the advantage of using ABC/abstractmethod is solely that instanciation is forbidden unless all methods have been implemented